# Can An Odd Set of Ordered Elements With this Specified Operation Arrive at any Permutation?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Sorry for the wordy or ambiguous title - I'm not *super* jargon familiar. Tags/better title suggestions accepted. Here is the set-up (from a game of Magic: the Gathering, no less):

Set L is of size n where **n is odd**. For simplicity, let set L be the integers from 1 to n:
$$L=(1,2,...,n)$$

If I define two functions such that:
$f(L)= (3,4,...,n,1,2)$ and $g(L) = (3,4,....,n,2,1)$

is it possible, through combinations of $f$ and $g$, to arrive at any desired ordering or permutation of $L$?

Non-mathy, Magic: the Gathering version: I can take the top two cards of my deck and put them on the bottom in any order I want, and I can do this any number of times. Can I sort my deck?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Let's fix an initial ordering of your library $a_1,...,a_n$ where $a_1$ is the top card and $a_n$ is the bottom card and $n$ is odd. It can shown that any permutation can be written as the product of *transpositions* which are just permutations in which two elements are swapped and everything else stays the same. We will show that we can make an arbitrary transposition using the given operation.

Fix $i,j \in \{1,...,n\}, i < j$. We can repeatedly put the top two cards on the bottom in the same order until we reach the $a_i$ is in the top card (note that you  have to go through your deck twice to achieve this if $i$ is even). Then put $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$ on the bottom of your library in the opposite order. So the new order of your deck will be (starting with the top card)
$$
a_{i+2}, a_{i+3},...,a_j,...,a_{i+1},a_i
$$
Each time you do this you effectively move $a_i$ one card closer to $a_j$, while leaving the order of the remaining cards in place. Eventually the top of your deck is $a_i,a_j$, so then you can swap those two and put them on the bottom. Now your ordering looks like $$...a_{j-1},a_i,a_j,a_{j+1},...$$
. Now we repeat the process of putting the top two cards on the bottom in the same order until $a_j$ is *second* from the top, then we put the top two cards of our library on the bottom swapping the order and essentially moving $a_j$ towards the initial location of $a_i$, while leaving the rest of the order in place. Thus we have been able to generate an arbitrary transposition, and can achieve any permutation (i.e. you can stack your deck).

This is not necessarily the most efficient way of achieving an arbitrary permutation, but it is deterministic, so you should be allowed to just stack your deck.